# Component Initialization failing with NoProvider exception

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm developing an application with Angular 2 RC4 (keyword here is RC4) and I've developed a component which I want to use where and whenever needed.

To do so, I've developed this simple component:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Panel } from 'primeng/primeng';

@Component({
    selector: "bb-tile",
    templateUrl: "app/shared/tile/index.html",
    directives: [Panel]
})

export class BbTile{
    @Input() title: string;
    @Input() value: string;

    constructor(title: string, value: string) {
        this.title = title;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

And this is my template:

```
<p-panel class="boxesdashboard">
    <header>
        {{title}}
    </header>
        {{value}}
</p-panel>
```

Then, I call this component inside another component by using this code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
(...)
import { BbTile } from "./../../../shared/tile/tile.component";

@Component({
templateUrl: 'app/pages/users/dashboard/index.html',
selector: 'my-app',
// Honestly I'm not sure if all of these are required here
directives: [InputText, DataTable, Button, Dialog, Column, Header, Footer, Panel, ProgressBar, Dropdown,
    SplitButton, SplitButtonItem, Toolbar, SelectButton, OverlayPanel, Checkbox, ToggleButton, BbTile],
providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS, UsersService]
```

})

```
export class UsersDashboardComponent {
    // Data variables
    user: User = new PrimeUser();
    selectedUser: User;
    newUser: boolean;
    users: User[] = [];

    tiles: BbTile[] = [new BbTile("Celso", "300"), new BbTile("ZéTó", "400")];
    (...)
}
```

And on my userDashboardComponent html, I have the following:

```
<h1 class="ui-g-12 titlebox">Users Dashboard</h1>
    <div class="ui-g-6 tiles-flex-wrap">
        <bb-tile *ngFor="let t of tiles" [tile]="tile"></bb-tile>
    </div>
</h1>
```

However, whenever I run this I get a bunch of errors in my console regarding NoProviderExceptions:

`browser_adapter.ts:82 EXCEPTION: Error in app/pages/users/dashboard/index.html:20:3BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.ts:82BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup @ browser_adapter.ts:93ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.ts:58(anonymous function) @ application_ref.ts:374schedulerFn @ async.ts:148SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.ts:240SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:192Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.ts:133Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:93Subject._finalNext @ Subject.ts:154Subject._next @ Subject.ts:144Subject.next @ Subject.ts:90EventEmitter.emit @ async.ts:133onError @ ng_zone.ts:142onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.ts:95ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:336Zone.runTask @ zone.js:268drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:491ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:435
browser_adapter.ts:82 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for String!BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.ts:82ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.ts:70(anonymous function) @ application_ref.ts:374schedulerFn @ async.ts:148SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.ts:240SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:192Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.ts:133Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:93Subject._finalNext @ Subject.ts:154Subject._next @ Subject.ts:144Subject.next @ Subject.ts:90EventEmitter.emit @ async.ts:133onError @ ng_zone.ts:142onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.ts:95ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:336Zone.runTask @ zone.js:268drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:491ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:435
browser_adapter.ts:82 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.ts:82ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.ts:74(anonymous function) @ application_ref.ts:374schedulerFn @ async.ts:148SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.ts:240SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:192Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.ts:133Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:93Subject._finalNext @ Subject.ts:154Subject._next @ Subject.ts:144Subject.next @ Subject.ts:90EventEmitter.emit @ async.ts:133onError @ ng_zone.ts:142onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.ts:95ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:336Zone.runTask @ zone.js:268drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:491ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:435
browser_adapter.ts:82 Error: DI Exception
    at NoProviderError.BaseException [as constructor] (exceptions.ts:21)
    at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (reflective_exceptions.ts:59)
    at new NoProviderError (reflective_exceptions.ts:92)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (reflective_injector.ts:849)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (reflective_injector.ts:878)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (reflective_injector.ts:840)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (reflective_injector.ts:633)
    at ElementInjector.get (element_injector.ts:23)
    at ElementInjector.get (element_injector.ts:23)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (reflective_injector.ts:876)`

What am I doing wrong here? I've been over the docs and the only difference I see is that the examples use a Service/Provider to input data, where I don't really want that here, I want to be able to intialize the values directly.

I've been messing with Angular2 for a couple of weeks now, so this might be a newbie question, but I need to ask as other SO threads didn't provide an answer.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property of your Component `BbTile` is called  `title` and not `tile` !!
And you have to bind each value and cant just put in the whole object.

Use it like this:

`<bb-tile *ngFor="let t of tiles" [title]="t.title" [value]="t.value"></bb-tile>`

If you want to use it like your way (that i assumed) ..
You need to change it a bit..

```
export class BbTileModel {
   public title: string;
   public value: string;

   constructor (... init stuff here ...) { ... }
}

@Component({
    selector: "bb-tile",
    templateUrl: "app/shared/tile/index.html",
    directives: [Panel]
})

export class BbTile {
    @Input() tile: BbTileModel;

    constructor() { }
}
```

The Template:

```
<p-panel class="boxesdashboard">
    <header>
        {{tile.title}}
    </header>
        {{tile.value}}
</p-panel>
```

the array would be like this:

`tiles: BbTileModel[] = [new BbTileModel("Celso", "300"), new BbTileModel("ZéTó", "400")];`

and finally your ngFor:

`<bb-tile *ngFor="let t of tiles" [tile]="t"></bb-tile>`

Just wrote it down here, so its not copy and paste ready, but you should get the idea behind it! :)

Comment: I like this approach better. Thank you @mxii

Answer (score 1):

The specific error you are getting comes because of the constructor.  The constructor requires two string inputs.  When the component instance is created, it is created behind the scenes by Angular.  If Angular sees that there are parameters required for the constructor it will look through the list of Providers to find a matching Provider to generate the data to inject into the constructor.  In your case you have no injectable providers that produce strings so you get the error.

The more important issue you have here is a design issue.  You are trying to use the same Object (BbTile) as both a data holding object you use to store values (`tiles: BbTile[] = [new BbTile("Celso", "300"), new BbTile("ZéTó", "400")];`) and a visual component used by Angular to display values.  You shouldn't do that.  For the data-storage needs you end up needing a constructor which takes string parameters, while for the component you need an empty constructor (the data comes to in via the @Input() annotated properties).  There is also the fact that you are carrying the extra baggage of a Component around with your data storage (and possibly confusion when you think an instance of BbTile is used for display when it is one you created with new BbTile(...), which would not be the case).

Instead, use an array of different objects (or strings) to store the tile[] in the UsersDashboardComponent, maybe something like:

`tiles: any[] = [{"title": "Celso", "value": "300"}, {"title":"ZéTó", "value":"400"}]`

Then you pass the values to the BbTile using HTML parameters (which get wired to the @Input properties on the instance of BbTile Angular makes for you):

```
<h1 class="ui-g-12 titlebox">Users Dashboard</h1>
    <div class="ui-g-6 tiles-flex-wrap">
        <bb-tile *ngFor="let t of tiles" [title]="t.title" [value]="t.value"></bb-tile>
    </div>
</h1>
```

Your BbTile would remain mostly the same, but would have an empty constructor:

```
@Component({
    selector: "bb-tile",
    templateUrl: "app/shared/tile/index.html",
    directives: [Panel]
})

export class BbTile{
  @Input() title: string;
  @Input() value: string;

  constructor() { }
}
```

Comment: Upvoted because this is a valid answer. However, I'll accept @mxii's answer as his is more complete to this specific use case. Tks